# How to create group By in LINQ in a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am learning LINQ Query and stuck at one place. Suppose I have a `strongly typed datatable` like below

```
idGroup   idUnit    Status
  1        12        foo
  1        13        bar
  1        15        hello
  2        12        nofoo
  2        16        nohello
```

I want the result like below:

```
 int     Generic List of int
 1         12,13,15
 2         12,16
```

So more like I want to create a dictionary but **group by** it based on **idGroup**.

My Attempt:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> temp = Mydatatable.ToDictionary(p => p.idGroup, p => p.idUnit);
```

Error: Above LINQ will return me `<int>, <int>`, but my expected result is `<int>, List<int>`.`

I want something like below:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> temp = Mydatatable.ToDictionary(p => p.idGroup, 
                                                           p => p.idUnit.ToList());
```

Comment: `Mydatatable.GroupBy(x=>x.idGroup)` ? `Mydatatable.ToLookup(x=>x.idGroup)` ?

Comment: @L.B: I made an edit to my question. I have three columns but I want only two columns. Please see the original datatable once.

Comment: Unbreakable, groupby returns an IEnumerable of your type. So "Select" whatever you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the error is because in your `ToDictionary` the value you specify is the `idUnit` which is an `int` and not a `List<int>` (for instance writing `p => new List<int> { p.idUnit }` would resolve that error)

Then after that for a dictionary output first `GroupBy` and then `ToDictionary`. Otherwise you will get an exception stating the given key already exists in the dictionary.

```
var result = Mydatatable.GroupBy(key => key.idGroup, val => val.idUnit)
                        .ToDictionary(key => key.Key, val => val.ToList());
```

Another option is to use a `Lookup` instead of a `Dictionary` and then just

```
var result = Mydatatable.ToLookup(p => p.idGroup, p => p.idUnit);
```

Comment: @Unbreakable - update should not make a difference for given answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying your solution now. Will update/ask my doubts accordingly. :)

Comment: There seems to be slight oversight in your solution. The code `val => idUnit` needs to be replaced with `val => val.idUnit`. Kindly confirm

Comment: Worked like a Charm. thanks for helping a junior developer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157514/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-gilad-green).